# NodeJS console.log executing before executing the FOR LOOP

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to push some values to array by fetching data from Jenkins APIs, like below.

```
buildNum = 14;
async.waterfall([
function(callback){
for ( var i = buildNum; i > (buildNum-5); i--) {
  (function(){
        jenkins.build_info('BuildDefinitionRequest', i, function(err, data) {
            if (err){ return console.log(err); }

                var tmpObj = {};

                tmpObj.jobID = data.fullDisplayName;
                tmpObj.result = data.result;
                tmpObj.dateTime = data.id;
                console.log(tmpObj);

                finalArray.push(tmpObj);

            });
        })();
    }
    callback(null, finalArray, 1);
  },
  function(finalArray, value, callback){
    console.log(finalArray, value);
    callback(null, 'done');
  }
  ],function(err, result){
  });
```

But "callback(null, finalArray, 1);" is getting called before the for loop finish its execution.
When I am printing the value of "finalArray" inside the for loop I am able to see all the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically the for loop has finished executing, but the jenkins.build_info calls haven't. You cannot make async calls inside of a for loop like that and expect the for loop to only finish after all the calls are complete. You're already using async, so this is an easy fix. I would do something like this:

```
var buildNum = 14;
var builds = [];

// just builds a collection for async to operate on
for(var i = buildNum; i > (buildNum - 5); i--) {
  builds.push(i);
}

var finalArray = [];
async.each(builds, function(build, next) {
  jenkins.build_info('BuildDefinitionRequest', build, function(err, data) {
    if (err) { next(err); }

    var job = {
      jobID: data.fullDisplayName,
      result: data.result,
      dateTime: data.id
    };

    finalArray.push(job);
    next();
  });
}, function(err) {
  // this won't be called until all the jenkins.build_info functional have completed, or there is an error.
  console.log(finalArray);
});
```